# How to upload and associate an Image with a User in Parse.com (REST API), using Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, parse-platform

I am trying to associate an image or a file with an object in Parse.com using the REST API. The [Parse.com REST API Doc](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#files) is quite vague, it talks about first how to upload which is fine, and then how to associate. The only issue is that it doesn't show how to associate with a `User table`, only an `Object table`, so when I tried to associate with a user, it asked for a username and password, and the response is as if it tries to create a new `user`. When I tried to associate with a regular table `Company`, it create a new entry. Any help would welcome, this is the code I have so far.

This is the code to upload a file to Parse.com with REST

```
    let baseURL = NSURL(string: self.baseURL)
    let url = NSURL(string: "/1/files/pic.jpg", relativeToURL: baseURL)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.HTTPMethod = "\(HTTPMethod.POST)"
    request.addValue(appID, forHTTPHeaderField:  "X-Parse-Application-Id")
    request.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")
    request.addValue("image/jpeg", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let image = UIImage(named: "empAvatar")

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.9)
    let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    let param = ["userProfile":base64String]

    do{
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(param, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    } catch {
        print("ERROR: HTTP Body JSON")
    }

    request.URL = url
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        do {
            let imageDic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
            print("DATA: \(imageDic)")
        } catch {

        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

This is the code to associate a file with a user/object

```
let baseURL = NSURL(string: self.baseURL)
    let url = NSURL(string: "/1/users/", relativeToURL: baseURL)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.HTTPMethod = "\(HTTPMethod.POST)"
    request.addValue(appID, forHTTPHeaderField:  "X-Parse-Application-Id")
    request.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


   let param = ["name":"John", "picture":["name":"tfss-127e50c4-be6e-4228-b1a3-3f253358ac-pic.jpg","__type":"File"]]


    do{
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(param, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    } catch {
        print("ERROR: HTTP Body JSON")
    }

    request.URL = url
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        do {
            let imageDic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
            print("DATA: \(imageDic)")
        } catch {

        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

With the URL, I also tried:

```
 let url = NSURL(string: "/1/class/Company/", relativeToURL: baseURL)
```

And it just created a new entry.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

`POST` request will create new entry try using `PUT` method instead.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I changed to PUT, it requests the objectId of course which I provided, but it returns 400 error, ["error": Cannot update without a specific object id]

Comment: In here: let url = `NSURL(string: "/1/users/", relativeToURL: baseURL)` you should add user's `objectId`.

Comment: Thank you very much @njuri. You pointed me to the right direction and I was able to solve it. I had to create an update with a sessionToken and it worked!! Thanks..

Comment: I can't download the file after, would know the simplest way to download using the URL? This is my questions I just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377205/how-to-download-the-file-from-parse-com-using-the-rest-api