# How to download the file from Parse.com using the REST API?

Tags: ios, swift, rest, parse-platform, swift2

I found this question at [Parse.com file download question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907562/how-to-download-parse-com-file-type-using-rest-api), however, it only mentions that the file can be downloaded from the Url.  Also, the  [Parse.com REST Documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#files) only discuss upload file and associated with an Object.

I tried to access the URL only, but it returns an error.

Can anyone help with an example in Swift and using the REST API, how to download the actual file once you get the URL after querying the object?

This is the error I get:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa39940dcc0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1100 "(null)"}
```

This is my code in Swift 2.0:

```
func downloadFile(){
    let str = "http://files.parsetfss.com/c426b506-44da-447d-91d0-93f13980758b/tfss-127e50c4-be6e-4228-b1a3-3f253358ac24-pic.jpg"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue(appID, forHTTPHeaderField:  "X-Parse-Application-Id")
    request.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: str)
    request.URL = url

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if (error == nil) {
            do {
                let image = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data!, options: [])
            } catch {

            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

This is the JSON response I get when I query the object, and the url is what needs to be used in order to get the file:

```
"picture": {
"__type" = File;
name = "tfss-127e50c4-be6e-4228-b1a3-3f253358ac24-pic.jpg";
url = "http://files.parsetfss.com/c426b506-44da-447d-91d0-93f13980758b/tfss-127e50c4-be6e-4228-b1a3-3f253358ac24-pic.jpg";
```

Comment: Hard coding a URL like that seems risky, especially since Parse is ultimately a database where files and other bits & bytes can be adjusted arbitrarily.  Can you find that URL in a file column right now when you look in your Parse table via the website dashboard?  The URL might already be stale.

Comment: The URL was hard-coded just for this question, as I didn't want to post too much code just to get the answer. I first uploaded the file to /1/files/, then associated the file name with the Class table, so on the dashboard, you can only see the pointer, hence, it is not actually stored on the table of the object. I then send a GET request to get the object information. I am now at the above, when I query the object, the JSON contains the image URL which you then need to download. Just checked and the URL is the same after I query the object again. I will post the JSON below my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet your problem is in this line:

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: str)
```

"`str`" is a remote URL and not a local file path, and what that API is trying to do is create a local "`file:///`" url from the string you provided it.

Why not do:

```
let url = NSURL(string: str)
```

and see if that works better?

Comment: Thanks, Michael, this was definitely the problem! Works now. I have another problem - when I originally uploaded the file, the NSJSONSSerializaion throws and error when I cast the image to NSData, so I encoded to base64EncodedString, and it worked. Now when I get the image in NSData, it doesn't show the image. I tried UIImage(data: data), and also tried to encode to base64String, back to NSData, and then to UIImage, but still doesn't work. What is the most useful format to upload and than download?

Comment: That's actually a totally separate question from the one you just solved and you should post a new question on [so], since we're supposed to stay within the bounds of each question here.